# Wordpress NGINX Plesk rewrite rules + rewrite for a specific folder

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting, plesk

I'm running a Plesk server with wordpress sites. The site works fine using Apache as webserver and Nginx as a proxy. I want to switch from PHP-FPM handled by Apache to PHP-FPM handled by Nginx so Nginx will be the web server for that site.

I did the switch and I've added this rule:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
}
```

Wordpress is running fine. There's also a folder called serp with this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I need to convert these rules into nginx rewrite rules so both wordpress and the scripts inside that folder will work

Basically the URL that is not working is this:

```
https://mydomain.tld/serp/2?keyword=tyres&type=test-valerio&source=test-source
```

While the actual url would be this:

```
https://mydomain.tld/serp/2.php?keyword=tyres&type=test-valerio&source=test-source
```

What I've tested so far:

```
location /serp {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php break;
  }
}
```

So basically I need a rewrite so instead of using **2.php?** in the url to use **2?**

I'm not able to make the rewrite rule work. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: You need to use `rewrite...last` as the new URI will be processed by a different `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I came up with:

```
    location /serp {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }

    location /article {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
```